# use of the causative form in 「誰に何言わせる気もないよ！　しゃんとしてろ！」

Tags: causation

I came across this statement:

> 誰に何言わせる気もないよ！　しゃんとしてろ！

from the context I believe it roughly translates to:

> don't let what anyone says bother you! hold your head high/ keep your chin up!

my question is if this translation is valid why use the causative form and why not use 誰にでも.

Comment: Aside from the question itself, let me make sure whether the sentence is what you heard or saw written. Surrounding context would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 2):

> 「誰{だれ}に何{なに}[言]{い}わせる気{き}もないよ！」
>
> from the context I believe it roughly translates to:
>
> "Don't let what anyone says bother you!"

I am afraid that that is not what it means.  No sure where you get the negative imperative form "Don't let ~~~~"

The original sentence is a regular negative **statement**, not an imperative.

> "I have no intention of letting anyone/people/others say anything!"

It is indeed causative as it talks about not allowing others to say something.

> why not use 誰にでも?

Because that just will not fit the context.  「誰にでも」 means "anyone" only in the context of saying "anyone can do ~~", "anyone could understand ~~", etc.

You could, however, use 「誰にも」 without a 「で」 if you changed 「何」 to 「何も」 and 「気も」 to 「気は」.  The double-も is quite common and grammatical, but not triple-も.

Answer (score 1):

> "誰に何言わせる気もないよ！"

The translation is,

> I'm not willing to let anyone say something

誰に and 誰にも are used for negative and positive situation.

誰にでも is usually used for positive situation.

For example, you can say

> Anyone can do that => 誰にでもできる, 誰でもできる

But, below sentence is a little bit unnatural.

> Anyone can't do that. => 誰にでもできない

It should be 誰にもできない or 誰でもできない.

Although this difference is not critical to deliver your thought.